# Unable to save changes in QField

Tags: android, qfield

I am trying to set up QField for a project, and during testing I am not able to save changes to point layer, and get the error "Unable to save changes". Project is saved on internal storage, and the layer I am trying to edit is same CRS as the project, but a different layer is not. I have a Galaxy A21.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using https://inputapp.io

It is based on QGIS and has an easier interface.

To create a project, install the app and after launching, under Projects > Home, select **Create project**

This will start a QGIS project with OSM background and allows you capture data. You can optionally sign up the sync service (https://public.cloudmergin.com/) and synchronise your data to the web. There is a Mergin plugin in QGIS which you can configure and download the data directly in your QGIS.