# What causes the QField error message 'unable to save'?

Tags: qgis, point, editing, qfield

I cannot seem to find any information about this particular error message.

When trying to add a point feature in QGIS, I receive the message 'Unable to save' (see screenshot). I have tried to find other information on the web but did not result in any relevant information. The closest thing I got was this recent post, but the accepted answer (to use a different app) would not work for me ([Unable to save changes in QField](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401040/unable-to-save-changes-in-qfield)).

We're using the latest version of QField. Does anyone know how what's causing this error and how to solve it?

[image: QField error message]

Comment: Try to create a new project and start from the very beinning. Maybe it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your primary key or other required field is bring populated.